# xxamp connect to database using php

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp, localhost

I am using xammp to connect to localhost on my pc.I have the latest versions of php (PHP version: 5.5.38) and mysql. I am using port 8012 so when I access the website I am building I type the following url: localhost:8012/website/index.php. I can access the website without any issues.I created a config file to connect to the database. I created a new database. I added a new user with full privileges to the default users. When I try to connect to the database I get the following error: 
Warning: mysql_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\config.php on line 2. I have tried just about everything to connect but I am not having any luck. Here is my config file:

```
<?php
 $user='admin';
 $pass='password';
 $db ='website';

 $db = new mysqli('localhost:8012',$user, $pass,$db) or die("Unable to          connect");
 echo"great work !!!";
 ?>
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks. :)

Comment: As I understand your question, you use the same port for your website and for the access to the database. Are you sure your database is running on the port 8012 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be obvious, but if you're website is accessable on port 8012, your database is probably running on the default port of 3306.

Try adjusting your code to this and try again.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost:3306',$user, $pass, $db) or die("Unable to connect");
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I cant believe that I did not think of this. I dont know what I was thinking actually. I really appreciate your help and you taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 1):

You may be using that port for your site, but not neccassarily mysql. Try

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost',$user, $pass,$db)
```

or as suggested, even better specify the mysql port:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost:3306',$user, $pass,$db)
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to answer. I tried localhost a few times and this did not work. I should have tried 3306 as the port and will try that now as that is the port for mysql. Thanks again.

Comment: I got it first go. It was a rookie error and I should have known better. My mind was full of cluster yesterday. Thanks again.